# Difference Between Razor View taking a IEnumerable<Model> vs Model?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have seen some people write  `@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Weight>` at the top of their view and some write `@model WebApplication1.Models.Weight`

I wanted to know the difference between both.Like when to use what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A razor view which takes an `IEnumerable<Entity>` as a Model means that a collection of objects (e.g. view models, or entities) is passed as the Model to the page by the controller. e.g.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyNamespace.Entity>
```

would match a Controller action such as

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchByName(string startsWith)
{
    var entities = Db.Entities
       .Where(e => e.StartsWith(startsWith))
       .ToList();
    return View(entities);
}
```

So that the view will have access to multiple `Entity` objects (e.g. the page in question might be an `Index` or `Search result` page, where the entries could be listed in tabular fashion with a `foreach`)

In contrast, a razor view which takes a single object as a Model is just showing the one object, e.g.

```
@model MyNamespace.Entity
```

Would be used from a controller action such as

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var entity = Db.Entities.Find(id);
    if (entity == null)
        return HttpNotFound();
    return View(entity);
}
```

Means that the view has a single `Entity` model subject, e.g. the page might be showing the details of one `Entity` object, or allowing update, or insertion of just one `Entity`.

The corresponding `Model` instance object available to the page will be the according type of the `@model`.

One other point to note is that `IEnumerable` also expresses immutability, i.e. the View should read the collection, but may not e.g. `Add` or `Delete` entities from it (i.e. it is good practice to leave the scaffolded `IEnumerable` and not change this to e.g. `IList` or `ICollection`).